# How do I sync multiple source folders with lsyncd?

Tags: 16.04, sync

I have the following lsyncd script which will sync across my www folder from a single server to multiple destinations:

```
settings {
       logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
       statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status",
       statusInterval = 10
}

www_target_list = {
        "server_one:/var/www",
        "server_two:/var/www",
        "server_thr:/var/www"
}

for _, server in ipairs(www_target_list) do
        sync {
                default.rsync,
                source = "/var/www/",
                target = server,
                rsync = {
                        compress = true,
                        acls = true,
                        verbose = true,
                        owner = true,
                        group = true,
                        perms = true,
                        rsh = "/usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
                }
        }
end
```

What I'd like to do is have a second set of source folders that I'd like to sync with the servers. So with `/var/www`, I'd like to add `/var/folder`.

How would I go about doing this with lsyncd?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm stuck with the same problem. :(

Comment: @dotslash I posted an answer for how I solved it. It's probably not the best solution, but it works.

Comment: Thank you! I did end up doing something similar myself. I don't know Lua so there was no way I was going to write loops, but it looks like multiple `sync` blocks does the trick. :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a second set of folders below the first set in the config like this. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it works.

```
settings {
       logfile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.log",
       statusFile = "/var/log/lsyncd/lsyncd.status",
       statusInterval = 10
}

apache_list = {
        "[ip address]:/etc/apache2/sites-available",
        "[ip address]:/etc/apache2/sites-available",
        "[ip address]:/etc/apache2/sites-available",
}

for _, server in ipairs(apache_list) do
        sync {
                default.rsync,
                source = "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled",
                target = server,
                rsync = {
                        compress = true,
                        acls = true,
                        verbose = true,
                        owner = false,
                        group = false,
                        perms = false,
                        rsh = "/usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
                }
        }
end

www_list = {
        "[ip address]:/var/www",
        "[ip address]:/var/www",
        "[ip address]:/var/www",
}

for _, server in ipairs(www_list) do
        sync {
                default.rsync,
                source = "/var/www/",
                target = server,
                rsync = {
                        compress = true,
                        acls = true,
                        verbose = true,
                        owner = false,
                        group = false,
                        perms = false,
                        rsh = "/usr/bin/ssh -p 22 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no",
                        _extra = {"--chmod=0755"}
                }
        }
end
```